# Set tabBarController viewControllers property with array literal of more than 5 viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

So I'm trying to add a `viewController` to a `tabBarController` that should force the `moreViewController` since I have 5 already and I would be adding a 6th. I'm setting the `viewControllers` property of the `tabBarController` using an array literal. This seems like something that's really simple, but I can't seem to find anything on stack or in Apple's docs that say it isn't possible to initialize it like this.

Here's the code below and the output of the NSLog's when I was trying to debug the issue. I can't figure out why I can initialize the `viewControllers` property to be 6 objects instead of 5 like it's showing:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* navVC1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* navVC2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* navVC3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* navVC4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* navVC5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController* navVC6;

@property (nonatomic, retain) customVC1* vc1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) customVC2* vc2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) customVC3* vc3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) customVC4* vc4;
@property (nonatomic, retain) customVC5* vc5;
@property (nonatomic, retain) customVC6* vc6;

self.vc1 = [customVC1 loadFromNib];
self.vc2 = [customVC2 loadFromNib];
self.vc3 = [customVC3 loadFromNib];
self.vc4 = [customVC4 loadFromNib];
self.vc5 = [customVC5 loadFromNib];
self.vc6 = [customVC6 loadFromNib];

self.navVC1 = [[[CustomNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc1] autorelease];
self.navVC2 = [[[CustomNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc2] autorelease];
self.navVC3 = [[[CustomNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc3] autorelease];
self.navVC4 = [[[CustomNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc4] autorelease];
self.navVC5 = [[[CustomNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc5] autorelease];
self.navVC6 = [[[CustomNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc6] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[self.navVC1, self.navVC2, self.navVC3, self.navVC4, self.navVC5, self.navVC6];

NSArray* tBArray = @[self.navVC1, self.navVC2, self.navVC3, self.navVC4, self.navVC5, self.navVC6];

NSLog(@"Here's the number of VCs        %d",[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items count]); // this outputs 5
NSLog(@"Here's the array count        %d",[tBArray count]); // this outputs 6
```

Here's an excerpt from another method where I style the tabBar:

```
int index = 0;
UITabBarItem* tb = nil;

tb = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:index++];
[tb setTitle:@"vc1"];

tb = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:index++];
[tb setTitle:@"vc2"];

tb = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:index++];
[tb setTitle:@"vc3"];

tb = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:index++];
[tb setTitle:@"vc4"];

tb = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:index++];
[tb setTitle:@"vc5"];

tb = [self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:index++]; // this is the out of bounds crash
[tb setTitle:@"vc6"];
```

So the app is crashing on me and here's the out of bounds error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'`

**EDIT: Here's the solution:**

Thanks for the help everyone. Figured out that can't apply attributes directly to the `tabBarItems` using `objectAtIndex` once have more than 5 tabs since it seems the 5th tab once you go over 5 becomes an array of `viewControllers` which is the `moreViewController`. I just rewrote the code to apply all attributes directly to the `viewControllers` before adding them to the `tabBar` as follows:

```
UIImage* vc1TabIconSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarIconVC1Selected.png"]
                                   imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.savedTabViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"VC1"
                                                                         image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarIconVC1.png"]
                                                                 selectedImage:vc1TabIconSelected];
[self.vc1TabViewController.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor colorFromHex:@"424242"] } forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: So what's the problem? When you run the app, do you see the first four navigation controllers and the "more" tab?

Comment: Apologies. That was bonehead. It crashed with an out of bounds. Editing question.

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would cause that crash. Add an exception breakpoint and see what line causes the crash.

Comment: Updated to show where crashed. It's later when I try to style the tabBar. Basically, it's passing an array size of 5 instead of 6. I'm not sure why because if I run a count on the exact same array literal set to an NSArray object, I get 6.

Comment: Ok, so I still want to know what's the problem? Do you get the controllers added to the tab bar controller that you expect? The logs you get are correct -- the tab bar should have 5 items. Four tabs with navigation controllers, and the more tab.

Comment: Issue was I was trying to set the attributes directly to the tabBarItems using objectAtIndex. Doesn't work once have more than 5 tabs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though there are 6 view controllers in `viewControllers`, `tabBar` still only has 5 `items`.

From the `UITabBarController` documentation:

> You should never access the tab bar view of a tab bar controller directly. To configure the tabs of a tab bar controller, you assign the view controllers that provide the root view for each tab to the viewControllers property.

Set the view controllers' `title` property; don't access `tabBar` directly.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. All makes sense now. Will post shortly what I did because I had to make sure as well that I had the right images and text color with all the different tabs. Hope it helps someone else out down the line.

Answer (score 1):

`UITabBarController` can only feature a maximum of 5 tabs. If you assign more than 5 view controllers to `viewControllers` the tab bar will only shows the first 4 tabs and a 5th tab called **More**, which shows a table view with rows for each remaining tab. **The point here is**, in this case, the `UITabBarController` shows that it has the full number of view controllers, while its `UITabBar` shows a maximum of 5 items.

`[tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:5]` is what made your app crash.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why that does not work, but you could also use

[self.tabBarController addChildViewController:viewController];

for each one

Comment: So I tried this. The app quits crashing but all the icons and text in the tab bar disappear. When I click where the "More" tab should be, it just sends me to selectedIndex = 4. So weird... I don't understand why it would be different.